# What is the type of the PropertyRegDataType output param of function SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty?

Tags: c++, windows, msdn

I'm trying to call the function `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` from `setupapi.h` has an output parameter named `PropertyRegDataType` of type `PDWORD`.  `PDWORD` is just a typedef which expands to `unsigned long near *`.

The [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has this to say about the `PropertyRegDataType` parameter:

```
PropertyRegDataType [out, optional]
    A pointer to a variable that receives the data type of the property that
    is being retrieved. This is one of the standard registry data types.
    This parameter is optional and can be NULL.
```

However, nowhere in the page does it mention what the "standard registry data types" are.  So my question is: What are the standard registry data types and how was I supposed to be able to determine this from reading that MSDN page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry data types are values such as `REG_DWORD`, `REG_SZ`, etc. They're documented in the [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724871.aspx) section in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884.aspx).

Comment: This appears to be what I was looking for.  I'm still annoyed that there seems to be no way to find this information from the documentation of the SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty function.

Comment: You're right, it should really be linked from the SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty page.